# production.ERROR: exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class cors does not exist'

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, autoload, autoloader

Locally I don't get an error, but when I deploy to my server (with Git), I get the following error:

```
production.ERROR: exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class cors does not exist' in /home/ruben/apps/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php:1244
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ruben/apps/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(1244): ReflectionClass->__construct('cors')
#1 /home/ruben/apps/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(1195): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('cors', Array)
#2 /home/ruben/apps/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(1733): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('cors', Array)
#3 /home/ruben/apps/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9459): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('cors')
#4 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 /home/ruben/apps/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9449): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 /home/ruben/apps/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(7375): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#7 /home/ruben/apps/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(7363): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#8 /home/ruben/apps/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(7348): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 /home/ruben/apps/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(2262): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /home/ruben/apps/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9467): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 /home/ruben/apps/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(2882): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#14 /home/ruben/apps/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9459): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#15 /home/ruben/apps/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(12755): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 [internal function]: Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#17 /home/ruben/apps/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9459): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#18 /home/ruben/apps/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(11390): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 [internal function]: Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#20 /home/ruben/apps/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9459): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#21 /home/ruben/apps/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(12496): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#23 /home/ruben/apps/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9459): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#24 /home/ruben/apps/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(12435): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 /home/ruben/apps/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9459): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#27 /home/ruben/apps/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(2932): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#29 /home/ruben/apps/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9459): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#30 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 /home/ruben/apps/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9449): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 /home/ruben/apps/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(2209): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#33 /home/ruben/apps/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(2192): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#34 /home/ruben/apps/public/index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#35 {main}
```

I've removed my /vendor folder and composer.lock file and ran composer install again. I checked, and the files for the class are there...

I hope somebody can help me.

**UPDATE**
I got some tips about case sensitivity. I really did not know how to use this tip, as I just used composer.json to install the packages. I decided to comment out the cors thingy, and the next error popped up:

```
production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'JWTAuth' not found' in
```

This is a similar error, with a class I added at somewhat the same time as the Cors class. I can't figure out why the classes aren't loaded.

Comment: Is your local machine windows and production linux by any chance? Check for case sensitivity given it's looking for `cors` with a lower case `c`

Comment: Yup. Specifically, you want to check that the filename of the class file exactly matches the name of the class in terms of case. The autoloader won't find a class named "cors" in a file named "Cors.php".

Comment: It seems like this is correct. Allthough I don't really know how to debug this properly. I just installed this package via composer: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm late,I just solved it.To your project root and running:

```
composer dump-autoload
```